# Unity Hololens cursor following users gaze off center?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm essentially trying to use my own code to accomplish what the BasicCursor and its corresponding script, Cursor.cs, does for gaze following using the [Microsoft Toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloToolkit-Unity/blob/master/Assets/HoloToolkit/Input/README.md). I believe its UpdateCursorTransform() method is what I'm trying to emulate, but I'm confused.

At the moment right now I have the cursor following the users gaze but it appears to be off center. The cursor is lower and to the left of where the users actual gaze is. What gives?

Here is my code..

```
// Do a raycast into the world based on the user's
// head position and orientation.
var headPosition = Camera.main.transform.position;
var gazeDirection = Camera.main.transform.forward;

RaycastHit hitInfo;
Ray ray;
Camera c = Camera.main;

ray = c.ScreenPointToRay(headPosition);

if (Physics.Raycast(headPosition, gazeDirection, out hitInfo))
{


    // If the raycast hit a hologram...
        objHit = hitInfo.transform;

    // Move the cursor to the point where the raycast hit.
        this.transform.position = hitInfo.point;

    // Rotate the cursor to hug the surface of the hologram.
        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hitInfo.normal);
}
```

Comment: And what do you do if the ray *doesn't* hit something (i.e. gazing off into space)?

Comment: `else
{  
this.transform.position = ray.direction;  
this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.zero);  
}`

Comment: Well `ray.direction` is a.... *direction* you probably don't want to set that to a *position*...

Comment: Right, I tried the headPosition (camera), but that was right in front.... it must headPosition with an increased Z value?

Comment: `headPosition + gazeDirection * some_distance`

Comment: You continue to be the most helpful individual on SO, for me at least. Thank you so much again. I've another question if you don't mind me shooting it your way. When calculating the distance between two vectors using the
[Distance()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) method it returns the distance but I am not exactly sure the unit of measurement its returning. For example, if I multiply the output by 13.33335 its almost exactly inches but it would be nice to get true equivalencies.

Comment: Unity units are supposed to be 1 meter. Mind, if your hololens camera's field of view is very wide or very narrow, that'll artificially influence what you see (things will seem closer/farther). Set the field of view to 60 degrees for the best experience.

Comment: @Draco18s Feel free to post your comment as a solution, I will gladly accept it as it was the answer I was looking for. As for the unit of measurement used by Unity I will most probably stick with the roughly 13x multiplication I have been using as it returns the result within a thousandth of its inches equivalent whereas when I do a conversion from meters to inches from the distance result Unity gives, its off by a decimal place.

Comment: @Draco18s Ooh actually, have you played with the Hololens at all? Specifically its Nagivation gestures. I'm rotating a object by moving my hand left to right to rotate about Y-axis, and up and down to rotate about the Z-axis. Any ideas on how to 'separate' axis rotations so that only one can occur at a time? Possible some sort of bounds on each movement but I couldn't pin it down as both move from negative to positive along their axis.

Comment: Posting an answer shortly. As for using the device, I have! Its in my desk drawer right now. Can't wait until the technology gets smaller, lighter, more powerful, and a larger holographic view area. Try using `NavigationRails_` If that doesn't work, check which axis has the larger value (don't forget to `Abs()` is) and set the other value to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity units are supposed to be 1 meter.

Mind, if your hololens camera's field of view is very wide or very narrow, that'll artificially influence what you see (things will seem closer/farther).  In a project I was working on, my coworker had put the objects that were to be the holograms 500 units away from the camera, then set the FOV to 10, which made them not sit in space where the real-world walls and floor were.  If you tried to walk around the object, you couldn't.

Set the field of view to 60 degrees for the best experience, I believe the prefab hololens camera has a field of view of 51.

I am not sure why trying to convert from meters to inches is giving you a value that's off by a power of 10 (should be a multiplier of ~39.37)